# I need help with a change of change of variables in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the first-order ODE:
                             $$\frac {dx}{dt} = ax + bx^3 -cx^5,$$
where $b\gt 0, c\gt0$. show that two of those parameters can be eliminated by an appropriate change of variables, so that the ODE can be written in the form
                             $$\frac {dy}{dr} = my + y^3 - y^5$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y(t)=Ax(Bt)$. Then 
\begin{align*}
y'(t)=ABx'(Bt)=AB(ax(Bt)+bx^3(Bt)-cx^5(Bt))=AB(a/Ay(t)+b/A^3y^3(t)-c/A^5y^5(t))=aBy(t)+bB/A^2y^3(t)-cB/A^4y^5(t).
\end{align*}
To obtain the desired form of the ODE it is enough to solve $bB/A^2=1, \ cB/A^4=1$.